# How can I merge 2 dataframes based on a list of tuples, where every tuple holds the relevant key from every dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 pandas dataframes that I want to merge into 1 new dataframe. I have a list of tuples, where the first element of each tuple is the index of the row in the first dataframe and the second element is the index of the row in the second one.

Here is an example:

```
### input sample

# table A
    col_a   col_b
0   1       2
1   4       5
2   7       8
3   1       1

# table B
    col_c   col_d
0   3       3
1   9       8
2   7       3
3   2       1

list_of_couples = [(0,1),(3,0)] # (index from table A, index from table B)

### expected output

    col_a   col_b   col_c   col_d
0   1       2       9       8
1   1       1       3       3
```

I've tried iterating over the list of tuples and adding merged rows one by one to a new df, but this takes a lot of time.
How can this be done efficiently? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dataframe out of the list of tuples, and then merge twice. e.g.

```
# Create df from list of tuples
tuple_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_couples, columns=['a', 'b'])

# Merge table_a with tuples
merged = pd.merge(table_a, tuple_df, left_index=True, right_on='a')

# Merge result with table_b
merged = pd.merge(merged, table_b, right_index=True, left_on='b')

# Removing intermediate join columns
merged = merged.drop(['a','b'], axis=1)
```

```
>>> print(merged)

  col_a col_b col_c col_d
0     1     2     9     8
1     1     1     3     3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create a temporary key to join on:

```
#unzip list_of_couples into index for table_a and table_b
a, b  = zip(*list_of_couples)

#Loop on length of index to assign same value of key to each table for the appropriate index
for i in range(len(a)):
    df_a.loc[a[i], 'key'] = i
    df_b.loc[b[i], 'key'] = i

#merge dataframes on 'key', remove NaN records and drop temporary 'key' column
df_a.merge(df_b, on='key').dropna(subset=['key']).drop('key', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d
0      1      2      9      8
5      1      1      3      3
```